# How to use xtensor from vba?

Tags: excel, vba, xtensor

Just hit xtensor, i like it and i would try to use it from vba (excel).
To keep this "testing" simple, i'm planning to use only matrices of doubles, which are passed to a C/C++ dll as LPSAFEARRAY.

1. Inside the dll, use the the received LPSAFEARRAY to build a 1D adapter,
   using the data pointer and the size (rows x columns). I think this is
   enough, for mapping operations.
2. The tricky part is in case I need the matrix, major concern being that 
   data is transmitted in the fortran (column-major) order. I did not find
   any 2D adapter, so my guess is that I have to transform the above 1D
   adapter:

   ```
   a) reshape it, to (columns, rows)

   b) transposed view of a)
   ```

Is the above correct, or are there easier, more straightforward methods?

Is there any speed penalty in this method of accessing the data?

Comment: please posts links to xtensor documentation

Comment: xtensor also allows for column-major. That might be the most natural for your data if it is indeed column-major.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly adapt 1D arrays to N-D containers with the layout you need via the adapt functions:

```
double* data = get_data_buffer();
auto adapter = xt::adapt<xt::layout_type::column_major>(data, {rows, columns});
```

See [adapt documentation](https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/xarray_adaptor.html#adapt-xarray-adaptor) for more details.